# Read JSON body Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple cloud function like so:

```
exports.sendReactionNotification = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("received reaction");
  functions.logger.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body["jsonPayload"]);
  return;
});
```

But the above logs "undefined" in the google cloud console. I have also tried dot notation like so: `req.body.jsonPayload.` But I get this error instead: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reaction')`

The webhook I am receiving the api call from sends a reaction, so that is where the "reaction" in the above error message comes from. I am tearing at my hair because this is mean to be simple, but I can't tell what the issue is.

This is what the JSON object looks like (**the result of the functions.logger.log(req.body) above**:
[image: JSON object]

Comment: Instead of living jsonPayload, try logging reaction instead. I think jsonPayload is the JSON that is supplied to the logger function.

Comment: Yes you were absolutely right @AlexanderN. If you could make your comment an answer so I could accept it, that would be great! Especially for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jsonPayload, try logging reaction instead. I think jsonPayload is the JSON that is supplied to the logger function.